# Spinner program exectues in Pycharm IDE but not in zsh terminal

Tags: python, linux, string, time, terminal

I'm using Pycharm Community Edition 2022 for running this simple Python program.

This spinner program is supposed to rotate the line in place for a number of 50 times with a delay so it's smoothes out the movement.

This is the working code:

```
#spinner.py

import time


spinner_items = "\\|/—"


for _ in range(50):
    for item in spinner_items:
        print(item, end = "")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print('\b', end="")`
```

My problem is when I try to run the program in the terminal with the command `python spinner.py` it doesn't output anything.

PyCharm Run result, how it should output:

[image]

Terminal command result (why is it stuck?):

[image]

Why doesn't the terminal output the same as the Pycharm IDE?
What could there be done so the terminal has the same output as the IDE?

I expected that the PyCharm IDE and the terminal output to be the same, being that it's the same program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `flush=True`

   ```
    import time

    spinner_items = "\\|/—"

    for _ in range(50):
        for item in spinner_items:
            print(item, end="", flush=True)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print('\b', end="", flush=True)
   ```
2. Use `-u` option, `python -u spinner.py`